# to check prime or armstrong in C programming using functions.(tsrn), i have done but it's not running neither showing any errors , help me through it

Tags: c

to check prime or armstrong in C programming using  functions.(tsrn), i have done but it's not running neither showing any errors , help me through it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void arm(int n);
```

```
int main()
    {
    int x;
    printf(" Enter the number you desire:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    //for prime numbers
   
    arm(x);
    return 0;

}

void arm(int n)
{
    int var, rem, sum=0, count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    var=n;
    while(var !=0)
    {
        var=var/10;
        count++;
    }
    var=n;
    while(var>0)
    {
        rem=var%10;
        sum=sum+pow(rem,count);
        var=var/10;
    }
    if(sum==n)
    printf("%d is an armstrong number", n);
    else
    printf("%d is not an armstrong number", n);
}
```

Comment: How are you running it? Any IDE?

Comment: do not use `pow` in integer operations.

Comment: visual studio, or what you mean, sorry i didnt get it

Comment: You have another `scanf()` in `arm()`. It's waiting for more input.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? I wouldn't use `pow` for integers, but the algorithm seems fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/qKcj4bdE1 Why does your program read a number, call the function with that number, then read another number which overwrites the passed in value?

Comment: yup actually i am trying for C program to check prime, armstrong, perfect number using functions all works fine expect armstrong but it works fine now, thanks but why you use this  while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1)
        {
            arm(x);
        }  can you please explain me thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Do not use `pow` as pow may return something like `99.9999999999999`
  and it, converted to `int` will be `99` not `100` as expected.
- If you struggling with your build environment you always can use
  online IDEs like godbolt. Here is the link to your program:
  https://godbolt.org/z/z9e5En3zo

```
int intpow(int x, int y)
{
    int res = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
       res *= x;
    return res;
}

void arm(int n)
{
    int var, rem, sum=0, count=0;
    //scanf("%d",&n);
    var=n;
    while(var !=0)
    {
        var=var/10;
        count++;
    }
    var=n;
    while(var>0)
    {
        rem=var%10;
        sum=sum+intpow(rem,count);
        var=var/10;
    }
    if(sum==n)
    printf("%d is an armstrong number", n);
    else
    printf("%d is not an armstrong number", n);
}
```

Comment: Minor: In _general_, `int res = x; for(int i = 1; i < y; i++)` better as `int res = 1; for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)` to handle `intpow(x, 0)` - even though that does not occur in OP's case.